# Working with wt-forms validators in flask

Tags: python, flask

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, session, redirect, url_for
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask_moment import Moment
from flask_wtf import FlaskForm
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import DataRequired

app = Flask(__name__)
class NameForm(FlaskForm):
    name = StringField('What is your name?', validators=[DataRequired()])
    submit = SubmitField('Submit')


@app.route('/', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
def index():
    form = NameForm()
    if form.validate_on_submit():
        session['name'] = form.name.data
        return redirect(url_for('index'))
    return render_template('index.html', form=form, name=session.get('name'))
```

I am new to flask, when I try to submit text in the field I get this error

```
TypeError: validate() got an unexpected keyword argument 'extra_validators'
```

this is how I run the form in my index.html
`{{ wtf.quick_form(form) }}`

is there something I need to add to the `NameForm` class or how do I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Try updating `wtforms` with

```
pip install --upgrade wtforms
```

`FlaskForm` is based on `wtforms` `Form` and `validate_on_submit` calls `validate`, but before version 2.3.1 ([changelog](https://wtforms.readthedocs.io/en/2.3.x/changes/#version-2-3-1)) `validate` didn't have the `extra_validators` parameter, hence the error.